# How do I add a user in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-administration, user-management

Specifically, what commands do I run from the terminal?

Comment: Aside from the fact that it seems to be a badge grab, why is this getting voted down so hard?

Comment: Probably because it is a really simple question. A quick search in google would give the answer.

Comment: Google is your friend.  Also, this belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: Feel free to add it there. The question predates ServerFault.

Comment: I don't have anything against this question, I'm just moving it to the more appropriate SE.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Without a home directory

```
sudo useradd myuser
```

With home directory

```
sudo useradd -m myuser
```

Then set the password

```
sudo passwd myuser
```

Then set the shell

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash myuser
```

Comment: unfortunately, I indeed follow this to add a user, and then get the error 'Access denied' when I try to sign in with it. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 34):

Here's the command I almost always use (adding user kevin):

```
useradd -d /home/kevin -s /bin/bash -m kevin
```

Answer (score 17):

There's basicly 2 commands to do this...

- useradd
- adduser (which is a frendlier front end to useradd)

You have to run them has root.
Just read their manuals to find out how to use them.

Comment: The adduser is so efficiently.