# Dockerfile/npm: create a sudo user to run npm install

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker

Creating a `Dockerfile` to install a node framework that we've created (per my earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873789/docker-installing-a-node-js-application-has-issues-since-docker-runs-as-root/21888825?noredirect=1#21888825)):

```
# Install dependencies and nodejs
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install git
RUN apt-get install -y git

# Bundle app source
ADD . /src

# Create a nonroot user, and switch to it
RUN /usr/sbin/useradd --create-home --home-dir /usr/local/nonroot --shell /bin/bash nonroot
RUN /usr/sbin/adduser nonroot sudo
RUN chown -R nonroot /usr/local/
RUN chown -R nonroot /usr/lib/
RUN chown -R nonroot /usr/bin/
RUN chown -R nonroot /src

USER nonroot

# Install app source
RUN cd /src; npm install
```

The problem is that npm expects to be run not as root -- is there a way to chain a series of `sudo useradd` commands to create a temp user that has sudo privileges that I can then switch to `USER` to run the `npm install`?

EDIT: updated the above, now getting this issue after successfuly creating a user and getting to the `npm install` line and choking:

```
 Error: Attempt to unlock javascript-brunch@1.7.1, which hasn't been locked
     at unlock (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1304:11)
     at cb (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:646:5)
     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:655:20
     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1282:20
     at afterMkdir (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1013:14)
     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
 If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
 including the npm and node versions, at:
     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Comment: Any reason not to use 'npm -g install' for a global installation of the package?

Comment: yeah, this is installing all the contents of `package.json`, not one package.

Comment: Would you mind providing e.g. the package.json file that you're using, to help others to reproduce the very same issue?

Comment: I get the same error. Have you solved this Attempt to unlock problem somehow?

Comment: I solved it with su -l noroot -c 'npm install' instead of the USER statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your "Attempt to unlock" issue, try cleaning the npm cache first by issuing

```
npm cache clean
```

After that, run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 8):

The "Attempt to unlock" issue is often caused by not having the environment variable `HOME` set properly.  `npm` needs this to be set to a directory that it can edit (it sets up and manages an `.npm` directory there).

You can specify environment variables in your `docker run` call with e. g. `docker run -e "HOME=/home/docker"`.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar npm install error when I was trying to execute is as a non-root user in my Dockerfile.  Svante's explanation of the issue is bang on, npm does some caching under the $HOME dir.  Here's a simple Dockerfile that works with npm install:

```
FROM dockerfile/nodejs

# Assumes you have a package.json in the current dir
ADD . /src

# Create a nonroot user, and switch to it
RUN /usr/sbin/useradd --create-home --home-dir /usr/local/nonroot --shell /bin/bash nonroot 

RUN chown -R nonroot /src

# Switch to our nonroot user
USER nonroot

# Set the HOME var, npm install gets angry if it can't write to the HOME dir, 
# which will be /root at this point
ENV HOME /usr/local/nonroot

# Install app source
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
```