# docker: having trouble running npm install after creating a new user

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, docker, coreos

So I have another follow-up question regarding installing a node.js-based framework under Docker on CoreOS, per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873789/docker-installing-a-node-js-application-has-issues-since-docker-runs-as-root).

So, because `npm` is finicky about installing from `package.json` via root, I've had to create a nonroot sudo user in order to install the package. This is what my `Dockerfile` currently looks like inside of our repo, building off of an ubuntu image:

```
# Install dependencies and nodejs
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install git
RUN apt-get install -y git

# Bundle app source
ADD . /src

# Create a nonroot user, and switch to it
RUN /usr/sbin/useradd --create-home --home-dir /usr/local/nonroot --shell /bin/bash nonroot
RUN /usr/sbin/adduser nonroot sudo
RUN chown -R nonroot /usr/local/
RUN chown -R nonroot /usr/lib/
RUN chown -R nonroot /usr/bin/
RUN chown -R nonroot /src

USER nonroot

# Install app source
RUN cd /src; npm install
```

I know that this is an inelegant way to do things, but I'm otherwise at a loss as to how to complete an npm install here. When I try the above, I get errors on all of the packages as they try to install:

```
 Error: Attempt to unlock javascript-brunch@1.7.1, which hasn't been locked
     at unlock (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1304:11)
     at cb (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:646:5)
     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:655:20
     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1282:20
     at afterMkdir (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1013:14)
     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
 If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
 including the npm and node versions, at:
     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

 ...
```

Any thoughts as to how I should modify my Dockerfile? I can only assume that this is some permissioning issue having to do with the way that I've provisioned the `nonroot` user above that might be particular to the Docker framework; I have no problem doing this kind of thing on just a vanilla ubuntu install, albeit not from script.

Comment: Why don't you tty into your container and `sudo su - nonroot` and run the exact same command, then that'll give you better idea on what's wrong

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906419/dockerfile-npm-create-a-sudo-user-to-run-npm-install), unless I missed an essential difference :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

so it turns out that this may be [an issue with docker](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4614).

was able to get around this by switching from `USER nonroot` to `RUN /bin/su nonroot` instead, afterwards everything worked fine.

Comment: also the `/src` dir was the only one that I needed permissions on

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the similar mistakes when trying to create any yeoman project and finnally found the solution :)

I was getting that error because the owner of .npm folder in my home directory was "root" user so I used

```
sudo chown [username] .npm
```

and now I can use Yeoman and npm without errors :)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

I have a couple of suggestions for modifications/suggestions:

- Cache your node modules earlier in the `Dockerfile` using something like this (put this right after the `apt-get`:

  ```
  ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
  RUN cd /tmp && npm install
  RUN mkdir -p /src && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /src
  ```

  This way if your application code changes you aren't rebuilding all your node modules each time. Put this before your `ADD . /src`. More details/examples are available in [my blog post](http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/) article.
- You shouldn't need to worry about running things as root in your `Dockerfile`... that is the default. Perhaps your problem isn't related to root but to the content inside your host's directory. Do you maybe need to clean out a lockfile from your code's dir?

Comment: Why do we need to copy package.json to a temporary folder and not directly to /src?

Comment: Dockerfile builds check each step to see if anything has changed - if nothing has changed, it can reuse a cached build step. If you do the `package.json` first as a separate step, if your code has changed but your package.json has not, it won't have to reinstall your `node_modules`.

Comment: very helpful - to go along with this - here is a good article on this approach:  http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/

Comment: Rather than moving to /src, just `COPY package*.json ./` early, then `RUN npm install`, then copy everything else with `COPY . .` That way, if no packages changed, you don't need to reinstall all npm packages.