# Lsyncd between two EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keygen, lsyncd

I have two EC2 instances and i am trying to sync a directory between the two of them.

I have set up the lsyncd service on one of the instances and was able to sync a directory to different directory on the same instance.
Now i am trying to sync the same directory with the second instance and it is not working.

The reason it is not working is that I am not able to put the key that was generated on the first instance using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` on the second instance in order to allow them access each other.

I have tried `sudo ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/key ec2-user@ip-of-second-instance` but it did not work.
I have also tried to manually copy the public part from the `key.pub` file of the first instance to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the second instance but it did not work either.

That is my lsynd configuration settings:

```
settings = {
    insist = true,
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status"}

sync {
        default.rsyncssh,
        source = "/home/ec2-user/IntSrv/Sync",
        host = "second-instance-ip",
        target = "/home/ec2-user/GenSrv/Sync",
}
```

What am i doing wrong? How can i fix that issue?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you ssh between the instances, using the same keys?

Comment: No. I also tried `sudo ssh -i /path/to/key ec2-user@ip-of-second-instance` and it didn't work. I used the key I am using to log into the instances from my laptop.

Comment: AWS has service known as EFS. Do you know about it ?

Comment: No. Is that for syncing? I was going for the lsyncd because i am familiar with it and already worked with it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start again with the keys.

You should really be [generating your own keys for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3659691/174777). Then, for each user you want to grant access to the instance, add their key to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file, either for the `ec2-user` or preferably [create a user account for them first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38289/174777) and add it to their `authorized_keys` file.

The keys generated by Amazon EC2 should be used to gain *initial access* to your instances. Then, **proper security practice** is to remove that key and add your own keys. This way, you have each person accessing via their own keypair, which can be removed if you wish to rescind access.

While I'm not familiar with `lsyncd`, I suspect that if you get `ssh` working, then `lsyncd` will probably work fine, too.

So, quick summary:

- Generate a key for YOU using `ssh-keygen`
- Connect to the desired instances, and add your public keypair to `authorized_keys` within the desired user home directory
- Use those keys instead of the ones generated by Amazon EC2

Comment: Ok. Will try those steps later.  Still, that does not really help me, as i said before i have no issue with connecting to each instance from my computer using the provided key.